# Rails 5.2 Active Storage get permanent link to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, trix

Im using active storage as the file uploads for trix, when I upload a file in trix, I send an xhr request to rails and rails responds with the image  url. However, since I'm saving this URL in a text field (trix) I need rails to respond with a permanent url, otherwise the image breaks after the url expires.

So far I have tried every way I know how, or can find on SO and other sources, but to no avail.

How can something so fundamental be so hard??

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it.

`json.image_url Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image.image)`